# Docker: MongoDB init script fails to run - Authentication error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker

I am expanding my docker-compose.yml for MongoDB container. I want to add some initial data.

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db:cached
      - ./fixtures/mongo_import.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_import.js

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: root 
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: root

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

When I am running this script I get an error in mongo container logs that user root is not existing.

So I have created a mongo_import.js script, it looks like this:

```
db.auth('root', 'root')

db = db.getSiblingDB('licensing')

db.createUser({
  user: 'root',
  pwd: 'root',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'root',
      db: 'admin',
    },
  ],
});
```

It doesn't work. When I go to the shell in this container and run `mongo mongo_import.js` I get:

```
# mongo mongo_import.js
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("b148691b-d585-48e9-9cdd-1d58ad4a4294") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.10
Error: Authentication failed.
2019-05-31T10:21:36.788+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on licensing to execute command { createUser: "root", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 }, lsid: { id: UUID("b148691b-d585-48e9-9cdd-1d58ad4a4294") }, $db: "licensing" } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1491:15
@mongo_import.js:5:1
failed to load: mongo_import.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
```

to your environment variables.

If you use a `.js` script, you have to define the auth database with the variable `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`.

If you do not set this value, the script will authenticate in `test` database.